# Why does importing a module with the right name give me a ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, import, module, directory, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to run the main.py module, as the picture bellow shows, the name is correct, both Letra.py (which is importing from widgets.py) and widgets.py are in the same directory. Widgets.py is not importing anything but "pyglet" which is a library I'm using (and probably irrelevant to this problem).

The picture already shows header code from Letra.py. Here is the header code from main.py

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from partida import Partida
import Widgets.widgets as widgets
import Widgets.Letra as Letra

class Janela(pyglet.window.Window):
    #etc...
```

Here is the error it is producing when I try to run main.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mecha\sopa\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Widgets.Letra as Letra
  File "C:\Users\mecha\sopa\Widgets\Letra.py", line 2, in <module>
    from widgets import Widget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgets'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

where is the `__init__.py` in the folder Widgets? For a folder or subfolder to be recognized as a package, it has to have `__init__.py`. Only then you can use the dot notation `Widgets.letra` or `Widgets.widgets` to import the required modules into other modules.

Answer (score 0):

To import `widgets` from main.py, you wrote this line:

```
from Widgets.widget import widget
```

But in Letra.py you wrote:

```
from widgets import Widget
```

Of course only one of these forms can work.  Since the first one works,  your environment is set up such that the proper name for the module is `Widgets.widget`, not simply `widget`.

Perhaps some confusion results from a misunderstanding of the first form. It imports Widget.widget and assigns the name "widget" to that import.  But that name is visible only within the module main.py.  A different module, in this case Letra.py, knows nothing about that assignment.